# What is $E \cap A$ where A is an algebra of subsets of $X$

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am having some confusion around the intersection of sets when the elements of one of the sets are sets themselves.

Let $X = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$

Let $\mathcal{A} = \{\varnothing, \{1, 2, 3\}, \{4, 5, 6\}, X\}$ be an algebra of subsets of $X$.

Let $E = \{1, 2\}$ be a subset of $X$.

What is $E \cap\mathcal{A}$?

**Option 1**

It is  $\varnothing$ as $E$ is not equal to any of the four elements of $\mathcal{A}$.

**Option 2**

It is  $\{\varnothing, \{1, 2\}\}$.

Which is correct? Or are both incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 is correct in the set-theoretic sense, intersection of sets--though it's because neither $1$ nor $2$ is an element of $\mathcal A,$ not because $E\notin\mathcal A$.

In the measure-theoretic sense (as martini points out below), this notation instead indicates the algebra on $E$ induced by $\mathcal A$--that is, $E\cap\mathcal A=\{E\cap A:A\in\mathcal A\}$--and in that context, option 2 is correct.

**Upshot**: It depends on what you're doing, but since you're dealing with algebras of sets, I'd wager that option 2 is the appropriate one.

Comment: In measure theoretic context, there is sometimes $E \cap \mathcal A$ used as an abbreviation for $\{A \cap E \mid A \in \mathcal A\}$ where $\mathcal A$ is some algebra or ring of sets.

Comment: Ah! So it may just be intended to be the algebra on $E$ induced by $\mathcal A$?

Comment: Yes that is the context it is coming from.

Comment: What exactly am I looking to 'match up' here...when I am intersecting $E$ with $A$? It seems $E$ consists of points, yet $A$ consists of sets...

Comment: @sonicboom: See my updated answer.

Comment: @CameronBuie Ok, looks very confusing the way there can be two different results for the same statement...I would have thought that there was only one correct answer in the case of intersection of sets. I'm only starting measure theory so maybe I'll get a better idea of it as time goes on.

Comment: @sonicboom: Unfortunately, using a particular bit of notation in different ways depending on the context is far too common. It saves us from having to invent new notation, but it can certainly lead to confusion.